# Criar uma coluna com case_when com intervalos aparece erro

Tags: array, r, syntax-error

> Tenho esta base de dados e pretendo criar uma nova coluna com esta
>   estruturação (ver imagem). Por exemplo, se a linha na coluna Calendar_Week tiver um valor entre 36 e 45 é suposto a nova coluna Quartile ficar com o número "1".

```
datanew1$Quartile <- case_when(
  datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(36,45) ~ "1",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(46,52)+seq(1,5) ~ "2",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(6,16) ~ "3",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(17,27) ~ "4"
)
```

> O problema é que o código me está a dar um erro :

```
"1: In datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(36, 45) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In seq(46, 52) + seq(1, 5) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(46, 52) + seq(1, 5) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(6, 16) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
5: In datanew1$Calendar_Week == seq(17, 27) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

> Alguma ideia em como resolver isto? Obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

> Na verdade, consegui resolver o problema desta forma:

```
datanew1$Calendar_Week <- as.numeric(datanew1$Calendar_Week)
datanew1$Quartile <- case_when(
  datanew1$Calendar_Week %in% seq(36,45) ~ "1",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week %in% seq(46,52) ~ "2",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week %in% seq(6,16) ~ "3",
  datanew1$Calendar_Week %in% seq(17,27) ~ "4"
)
```